# Upload interim maven dependencies to Nexus 3

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm trying to use maven to download artifacts for remote repos to my local nexus. I used the mirror tag in my maven settings.xml but find that maven complains its not able to find an artifact that does not exist in my local nexus and fails the build. I want maven to discover if a dependency exists in nexus first and if it doesn't then download the dependency from the remote repo to nexus. What settings do i need for that to happen

Here is my config in maven settings.xml to use nexus as a mirror  :

```
    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0                 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
      <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
      </activeProfiles>

      <servers>
        <server>
          <id>nexus</id>
          <username>username</username>
          <password>password</password>
        </server>
      </servers>

      <mirrors>
        <mirror>
          <id>nexus</id>
          <name>Internal nexus mirror of central</name>
          <url>https://nexus-url/repository/maven/</url>
          <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
      </mirrors>
      <profiles>
        <profile>
          <id>nexus</id>
          <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
          </activation>

          <repositories>
            <repository>
              <id>nexus</id>
              <layout>default</layout>
              <url>https://nexus-url/repository/maven/</url>
              <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
              </releases>
              <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
              </snapshots>
            </repository>
          </repositories>

          <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
              <id>nexus</id>
              <url>https://nexus-url/repository/maven/</url>
            </pluginRepository>
          </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
      </profiles>

      <pluginGroups/>
    </settings>
```

I am running the build using Jenkins and my JenkinsFile looks like below:

```
    pipeline {
        agent { node { label 'host' } }
        environment {
            M2_HOME = '/usr/share/jenkins/apache-maven'
            M2          = "${M2_HOME}/bin"
            PATH        = "${M2}:${PATH}"
        }
        stages {
            stage('Build') {
                steps {
                    dir('directory') {
                        sh "#!/bin/bash \n" +
                            "mvn -T 1C install -am -Dfile=snapshot.tar -DgroupId=com.blah -DartifactId=app -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DgeneratePom=true -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/home/jenkins/.keystore/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

None of the dependencies seem to get downloaded to Nexus, instead it only gets downloaded locally to the Jenkins node which is not helpful since the Jenkins nodes are ephemeral docker containers. How do I get the dependencies to be downloaded from Maven Central, Spring and other remote repos and uploaded to Nexus?

EDIT : We are using Nexus 3. Was reading some blogs that Nexus 3 doesn't allow downloading remote indexes. Is this the issue that I am not able to get Nexus to download the dependencies?

Comment: Please show the full settings.xml file? Are you using this setup for your settings.xml file https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/2.8/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html ?

Comment: Updated with complete settings.xml. I checked the link you referenced and I see repos and plugin repos url specified as <url>http://central</url>. I listed the same nexus url in my config since the repo on nexus is setup as proxy repo to the remote repo. Was confused if I should be listing <url>http://central</url> in my settings.xml or if that was just a placeholder for an actual url for Spring or Maven remote repo

Comment: Can you please show also a log file while some dependencies are not being downloaded ? What kind of messages do you get ? BTW: Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: I am using Maven 3.5.2 and Nexus 3.7.1.02. I am basing this on not being able to see the dependencies when I browse through the Nexus repository manager. I expect to see something to show up under https://nexus-url/repository/maven/ or within the individual spring/apache repos in Nexus

Comment: I said: Have you log files during the build running and showing the errors ?